# Angular 4 directive outside of component

Tags: angular

I'd like to use angular directive on an element (server side rendered) on an existing website.

I'd like to keep the element (and it's nodes) in tact and just attach a directive to it. Wrapping it in a `component` - replaces the original element with a template.

`NgModule` wouldn't let bootstrap a directive.

Suggestions ?

Comment: It's just not supported. Angular 4 is most likely not what you want to use for your page.

Comment: I think you are searching for [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal). You will need a backend implementation of this. Currently I think you have one for Node and one for ASP.NET Core, but none for Java and Spring, nor any other environment.